# ImageView setImageBitmap method messes up the whole layout

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

there is a layout, where I have some buttons, controls and an imageView. When the layout shows up, everything is okay. But later, when the requested image (the image of the aveform) is downloaded and I try to set it to the ImageView with setImageBitmap. The whole layout become messed up. Here are some pics.

This is how the layout looks like, when image has not been downloaded:
[image]
This is after the setImageBitMap
[image]

Here is my xml (I use a custom subclass of imageView, but the error also occurs withz the original mageView)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:gravity="center"
>

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

     >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <adam.czibere.WaveFormSurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:thumb="@drawable/progress_fill" />

    </TableRow>


    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/currentPos"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:text="00:00.000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="/" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/endPos"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="00:00.000" />
    </TableRow>


    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/closebtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Close" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/playButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Play" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="ToggleButton" />

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Here is the extended imageView:

```
public class WaveFormSurfaceView extends ImageView {

public boolean isEditMode = false;
Bitmap waveform = null;
int touchCount = 0;
List<VerbaComment> myComments = new ArrayList<VerbaComment>();
int lastTouch_x = -1;

public WaveFormSurfaceView(Context context) {
    super(context);

}

public WaveFormSurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public WaveFormSurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

// copies the given waveform to a variable
public void setWaveForm(Bitmap b) {

    waveform = Bitmap.createBitmap(b.getWidth(), b.getHeight(),
            b.getConfig());
    // copy the pixel to it
    int[] allpixels = new int[b.getHeight() * b.getWidth()];
    b.getPixels(allpixels, 0, b.getWidth(), 0, 0, b.getWidth(),
            b.getHeight());
    waveform.setPixels(allpixels, 0, b.getWidth(), 0, 0, b.getWidth(),
            b.getHeight());

}

@Override
public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.setImageBitmap(bm);
    setWaveForm(bm);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    // System.out.println("waveform width: "+waveform.getWidth());

    // setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight());

    // setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec,heightMeasureSpec);
    // setMeasuredDimension(1000,200);

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // super.onDraw(canvas);

    // Create a paint object for us to draw with, and set our drawing color
    // to blue.
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    paint.setAlpha(50);

    Paint paint1 = new Paint();
    paint1.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    paint1.setAlpha(50);

    // draws the rectangle
    if (waveform != null) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(waveform, 0, 0, null);
        if (isEditMode) {
            for (VerbaComment vc : myComments) {

                System.out.println("drawing the comment... start: "
                        + vc.start + " end: " + vc.end);

                canvas.drawRect(vc.start, canvas.getHeight(), vc.end, 0,
                        paint);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("waveform width, height:" + waveform.getWidth()
                + " x " + waveform.getHeight());
    } else {
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50, paint);
    }

    // mImageView.setImageBitmap(map);
}



@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        if (isEditMode) {
            touchCount++;
            // lastTouch_x=(int)event.getX();
            // System.out.println("onTouch; touchCount: "+touchCount+" lasttouch_x: "+lastTouch_x);
            if (touchCount % 2 == 0) {
                VerbaComment temp = new VerbaComment(lastTouch_x,
                        (int) event.getX());
                myComments.add(temp);

            } else {
                lastTouch_x = (int) event.getX();
                System.out.println("onTouch; touchCount: " + touchCount
                        + " lasttouch_x: " + lastTouch_x);

            }
        }
    }

    invalidate();
    return true;
}

 }
```

And here is the activity:

```
public class AudioPlayerActivity extends Activity{
    // Hardcoded parameters for the Verba demo server
        private static final String ServerURL = "http://demo.verba.com";
        private static final String MediaPath = "C:\\Program%20Files\\Verba\\media\\";

        // Player user interface elements
        private Button mBtnPlay;
        private WaveFormSurfaceView mImageView;

        //private ImageView mImageView;
        private SeekBar mSeekBar;
        private TextView mCurrentPos;
        private TextView mEndPos;

        private Bitmap originalWaveForm;





        // THIS IS THE MEDIAPLAYER (has no UI, only loads and plays the audio)
        private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

        // HTTP URL for the audio waveform PNG picture
        private String getWaveformURL(String pCallURL) {
            return ServerURL + ":8089/a?" + MediaPath + pCallURL
                    + "?10000200240240240123023048240240240240240240";
        }

        // HTTP URL for the audio transcoded to MP3 format
        private String getMediaURL(String pCallURL) {
            return ServerURL + ":10100/getMedia?file=" + MediaPath + pCallURL
                    + "&format=mp3";
        }

        // Downloads the waveform image outside of the main GU thread
        private class DownloadWaveformTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
                try {
                    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(
                            getWaveformURL(myCallURL))
                            .getContent());
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mImageView.setImageBitmap(result);

            }
        }



        // Updates the seekbar outside of the main GU thread, started only after
        // MediaPlayer exists
        private class SeekBarUpdater extends Thread {
            float p=0;
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final SimpleDateFormat tf = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss.SSS");
                final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

                int currentPosition = 0;
                final int total = mMediaPlayer.getDuration(); // //returns in msec,
                                                                // final because we
                                                                // will use in the
                                                                // runnable

                // UI update must happen on the UI thread, so we post our actions
                // there in a runnable
                mCurrentPos.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        calendar.setTimeInMillis(total);
                        mEndPos.setText(tf.format(calendar.getTime()));
                        mSeekBar.setMax(total);
                    }
                });

                while (mMediaPlayer != null && currentPosition < total) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(50);
                        currentPosition = mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition(); // returns
                                                                                // in
                                                                                // msec
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        return;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        return;
                    }

                    // we are roughly adjusting for delays due to the thread
                    // communication
                    // currentPosition -= 100;
                    // if (currentPosition < 0 ) currentPosition = 0;
                    final int currPosition = currentPosition; // final because we
                                                                // will use in the
                                                                // runnable

                    p=(float)currentPosition/(float)total;

                    // UI update must happen on the UI thread, so we post our
                    // actions there in a runnable
                    mCurrentPos.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            calendar.setTimeInMillis(currPosition);
                            mCurrentPos.setText(tf.format(calendar.getTime()));
                            mSeekBar.setProgress(currPosition);
                            System.out.println("pecent="+p);
                            drawRectOnWaveForm(p);
                        }
                    });

                }
            }
        }




        String myCallURL;

        /**
         * Create a new instance of MyFragment that will be initialized
         * with the given arguments.
         */
        static MediaPlayerFragment newInstance(CharSequence url) {
            MediaPlayerFragment f = new MediaPlayerFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putCharSequence("call_url", url);
            f.setArguments(args);
            return f;
        }

        /**
         * During creation, if arguments have been supplied to the fragment
         * then parse those out.
         */
        @Override 
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            if (extras != null) {
                String value1 = extras.getString("call_url");
                if(value1!=null){
                    myCallURL=value1;
                }
            }

            DownloadWaveformTask task = new DownloadWaveformTask();
            task.execute();

            setContentView(R.layout.mediaplayer);
            System.out.println("AudioPlayerActivity setContentView, mycallurl: "+myCallURL);



            // part of the player UI
            //mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            mImageView = (WaveFormSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            mBtnPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playButton);
            mSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
            mCurrentPos = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currentPos);
            mEndPos = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.endPos);
            ToggleButton tb=(ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);

            tb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(isChecked){
                        mImageView.isEditMode=true;
                        mImageView.invalidate();
                    }else{
                        mImageView.isEditMode=false;
                        mImageView.invalidate();
                    }


                }
            });





            //
            mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                        boolean fromUser) {
                    if (fromUser) {
                        // we only update the player if the change comes from a user
                        // action
                        mMediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
                    }
                }
            });

            // IMPORTANT
            // - The DownloadWaveformTask part should go into the initialization of
            // the player fragment
            // - currently we are NOT handling currently the end of playback
            // situations, we should
            // - currently we are NOT releasing the MediaPlayer resource, we should
            // when a fragment closes
            mBtnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
                        if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                            mMediaPlayer.pause();
                            mBtnPlay.setText("Play");
                        } else {
                            mMediaPlayer.start();
                            mBtnPlay.setText("Pause");
                        }
                    } else {


                        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                        mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

                        // this updates the seekbar as the buffering happens
                        mMediaPlayer
                                .setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp,
                                            int percent) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                        mSeekBar.setSecondaryProgress((int) (mSeekBar
                                                .getMax() * percent / 100));
                                    }
                                });

                        try {
                            final String lMediaURL = getMediaURL(myCallURL);
                            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(lMediaURL);
                            mMediaPlayer.prepare(); // might take long! (for
                                                    // buffering, etc)
                        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        mMediaPlayer.start();
                        mBtnPlay.setText("Pause");

                        // we start the thread that updates the seekbar, based on
                        // the state of the player
                        SeekBarUpdater thread = new SeekBarUpdater();
                        thread.start();
                    }
                }
            });

            // Close button
            Button closeBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.closebtn);
            closeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //TODO ha megy a lejátszás, megállítjuk
                    if(mMediaPlayer!=null){
                        if(mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                            mMediaPlayer.stop();
                        }
                    }
                    finish();
                }

            });


        }

}
```

Comment: set `android:id="@+id/tableRow4"` layout width to `match_parent` instaed

Answer (score 0):

Okz here are some flaws i have got in your code

1. You are giving `android:layout_gravity`="center" to your `SeekBar` and on other hand you are giving it match_parent attribute
2. Why you are giving `fill_parent` to your `id/tableRow3`

and try to use `fill_parent` instead of match `_parent` because fill_parent is backword compatible

Comment: thx, seekbar is better now. But the buttons are still messd up. I dont understand why the first button became so big. It got wrapcontent attribute and all the butoon weights are 1.

Comment: I changed the tableRow to LinearLayout. And it solves the problem.

Comment: hmm RelativeLayout is batter than LinearLayout, LinearLayout takes more time and resources to parse